# CSS table border not showing in IE 10 or FF 22

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to edit the table borders using CSS and Dream Weaver but the borders aren't showing in IE 10 or FF22.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
padding:15px;
border-color:red;
}
.cell {
border-bottom-color:#585858;
border-bottom-width:medium;
border-right-color:#787878;
border-right-width:thick;
border-top-color:#000;
border-top-width:thin;
border-left-color:#000;
border-left-width:thin;
background-color:#BFFFFF;
alignment-adjust:central;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="cell"><center>This is my test table</center></td>
<td><center>blah blah blah</center></td>
<td class="cell"><center>ya ya ya ya ya</center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try "border-style" and "border-width" to cross check

Comment: That did it.  Adding border-style to the CSS allows the borders to be seen now.  Thanks!